# Use ant,How to open a url with multiple parameters

Tags: ant

I am using:

```
<exec executable="cmd">
<arg line="${argLine}" />
</exec>
```

when `argLine`

```
<property name="argLine" value="http://127.0.0.1:/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;style=120662"/>
```

with 2 params ,and i use `&amp;` escape `&` symbols

but only open `http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305`

the `style` param lost

**In short,i want run**

```
<target name="111test"> 
    <exec executable="cmd" output="e:/test.txt">
        <arg line="/c start '' 'http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;%3bstyle=120662'" />
    </exec>  
</target>
```

**2012-05-23 update**

Yes,Windows system

I change code to

```
<target name="111test">
    <exec executable="cmd" output="e:/test.txt">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="start" />
        <arg value="" />
        <arg value="http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;%3bstyle=120662" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

run ant

only open

```
http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305
```

I change "`&amp;%3b`"  to "`&amp;`"

also only open

```
http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305
```

But in cmd, i use

```
start "" "http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&style=120662"
```

can open `http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&style=120662`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly understanding what it's trying to open. Is it literally trying to open a URL with `***?skuId=305`, or are you trying to say it's trying to open the URL you gave it up to, but not including the semicolon?

If you are saying that it is leaving off the last part of your URL, you should understand that semicolons cannot be part of the actual URL you're sending. They're [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1178053/368630) and must be specially encoded.

Make sure that semicolon is even suppose to be there. When you do a *GET* request, you have the basic URL, and then after that URL a question mark. After that, you have a series of parameters you're passing to the URL with each parameter separated by ampersands. In your case, it looks like you want to send a request to URL:

- `http://127.0.0.1:/product/findSameStyleSku.json`

With the following two parameters:

- `skuId` = *`305`*
- `style` = *`120662`*

So, it looks like the semicolon is bogus. Otherwise, you're passing the parameter *`;style`* and not *`style`*. And, that doesn't seem it would be correct.

If you've determined that the semicolon is really suppose to be there, try replacing the semicolon in the URL with `%3b`:

```
<property name="argLine" value="http://127.0.0.1:/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;%3bstyle=120662"/>
```

---

## Response

> ,i'm sorry ,it does't Work correctly,I updated my question – feeling

Unfortunately, since this is on a Windows machine, and is something running locally on your machine, I can't run a test myself.

However, according to the first part of your post, you are attempting to run the following command:

```
C> cmd http://127.0.0.1:/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;style=120662
```

Later in your post, you say you want to run:

```
C> cmd /c start '' 'http://127.0.0.1/product/findSameStyleSku.json?skuId=305&amp;%3bstyle=120662'
```

The first certainly won't work from the command line. Does the second one?

I've done a few tests on my current computer using this:

```
<property name="argLine"
    value="http://etzahaim.org/index.php?option=com_content&amp;task=blogcategory&amp;id=15&amp;Itemid=34"/>
<exec executable="curl">
    <arg value="${argLine}"/>
    <arg value="--include"/>
    <arg value="--output"/>
    <arg value="curl.out"/>
</exec>
```

This is the `curl` command which fetches the URL. This URL is also uses a GET method, so it also has a question mark and some asterisks in the URL. This works for me.

Try switching from `<arg line='start' '' 'http://...>` to using `<arg line>` and see if that helps:

```
<target name="111test"> 
    <exec executable="cmd" output="e:/test.txt">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value=""/>
        <arg value="${argline}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I want to express the meaning behind,  
but,when i execute ,Ant build failed,warn:  The reference to entity "amp" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: @feilong -- Sorry, I mistyped it. I changed `&amp` to `&amp;`. The answer should now be correct.

Comment: @feilong See the response added to my original answer

Comment: @feilong I'm sure I must be missing something here. Have you tried running ant via `--verbose` or the `--debug` switch to see if this gives you any more information. Can you set a property with the URL and then print out that URL?