# Add a semicolon to the Codeigniter permitted URL chars

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I need to add a semicolon (;) to the Codeigniter permitted URL chars pattern, here is the code:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';
```

I need to add the semicolon (I need this because some semicolons are passed with the URL), but I don't know how to add it to the pattern.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You many not use semicolon's in the URL except for it's intended purpose.

[Can a URL contain a semi-colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178024/can-a-url-contain-a-semi-colon)

Does this not work?

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-;';
```

Comment: SMF uses it for their URLs eg:

.../forum/index.php?action=admin;area=regcenter;sa=settings

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the ';' in that config string.

Instead of a semicolon in the url, you could insert it's url encoded version '%3b'

So:

```
http://www.example.com/some%3bthing
```

%3b is a semicolon, such as %20 is a white space.

More info: http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_url_encoding_table.htm