# Reach a NetSuite RESTlet via OAuth

Tags: java, oauth, netsuite

The goal is to be able to call RESTlets using OAuth-header instead of NLAuth-header from my Java-application. In order to achieve it I took the following steps:

1. I created NetSuite Developer Community Account and got a testing environment with admin access (domain system.na1.netsuite.com).
2. I opened Setup --> Company --> Enable Features. Then opened the "SuiteCloud"-tab and checked the "Client SuiteScript", "Server SuiteScript" and "Token-Based Authentication" here.
3. I opened the edit-page of one of the roles (it is called "08: Inspection" here). On the "Permissions"-tab I opened the "Setup"-tab and added the following permissions to this role: "Access Token Management", "Log in using Access Tokens" and "User Access Tokens".
4. I edited my account to have that role: opened "Access"-tab while editing the user and on the"Roles"-tab I added that role ("08: Inspection").
5. I opened Setup --> Integration --> Manage Integrations --> New and created new application here ("TestIntegr"). The final page held two strings: Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. I saved them in my separate file.
6. I opened Setup --> Users/Roles --> Access Tokens --> New and created new token for my application+user+role. The final page held two strings: Token ID and Token Secret. I saved them in my separate file.
7. I used my test program to generate authorization header string and then used this string in rest-client (I used "Insomnia") to reach my dummy-restlet. Got "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT"-error.
8. In NetSuite audit-logs I can see failures on behalf of my user but without a role.

*More technical info on the 7th step with examples below.*

The URL I used to reach my dummy-restlet was https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=546&deploy=1

So I generated the "signature string" ("consumer_key" from step 5 and "token" from step 6):

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Frest.na1.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Fsite%2Fhosting%2Frestlet.nl&deploy%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3D17840f699409f5031c22a6e4af15961e9627c168cd0ae71f9c14f71b4097a0b6%26oauth_nonce%3D1444927941574%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1444927941%26oauth_token%3Df3c29a8b2c7988e00947d8c5836ef0ff1883556d96b8beac5bbbdda001ba0292%26realm%3DTSTDRV1403065%26script%3D546
```

Then I generated "signature" using this string and "consumer_secret&token_secret". The header then had the following look:

```
OAuth oauth_signature="7doRJOJyV36Av4e4BBUgoOPn7Vk%3D", oauth_nonce="1444927941574", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="17840f699409f5031c22a6e4af15961e9627c168cd0ae71f9c14f71b4097a0b6", oauth_token="f3c29a8b2c7988e00947d8c5836ef0ff1883556d96b8beac5bbbdda001ba0292", oauth_timestamp="1444927941", realm="TSTDRV1403065"
```

Then I used this header with my rest-client and got the "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT"-error (while NLAuth header works perfectly with this rest-client, this user and this dummy-restlet).

I checked my signature-algorithm with this online-tool: http://nouncer.com/oauth/authentication.html It shows the same results with the same tokens/timestamp/nonce/etc. I suppose I missed something during setting up NetSuite environment (user/role/something else). On the other side the NetSuite HelpCenter says: "An INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT error is returned when the nonce, consumer key, token, or signature in the OAuth header is invalid".

Please tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps seems to be correct as you are able to get consumer and user keys.

The probable error could be in your java code. I was able to get a successful response from a RESTLet using Java code. I used [Scribe-Java](https://github.com/scribejava/scribe-java) as OAuth 1a client library.

Below is my main method

```
OAuthConfig authConfig = new OAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", null, SignatureType.Header, null, null);
    Token token = new Token("TOKEN_ID", "TOKEN_SECRET");
    OAuth10aServiceImpl auth10aServiceImpl = new OAuth10aServiceImpl(new NetSuiteApi(), authConfig);
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "RESTLET_URL");
    request.setRealm("NS_ACCOUNT_ID");
    auth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(token, request);
    Response response = request.send();
```

you will also need to write NetSuiteApi class, as it is required by Scribe. Just, a framework overhead

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;

public class NetSuiteApi extends DefaultApi10a {

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Also, make sure that the user or user's has access to execute the RESTlet in its deployment.

Comment: Thank you, prasun! Your example with Scribe works like a charm. Feels like you were right about my java code. :(

Comment: @prasun I am not sure which version of `Scribe-Java` you had used for the above solution, but when I compile your solution with the latest version of `Scribe-Java-6.2.0` am getting some compilation errors `OAuthConfig cannot be resolved to a type`, `OAuthConfig cannot be resolved to a type`, `The method send() is undefined for the type OAuthRequest`

Comment: @ankit can you create a new question and put the details like stack trace, your sample code and the version of scribejava

Comment: Guys,
I am using Restlet with C# with TBA Oauth 1.0 and OAuthBase.cs whenever I append a special character with query string its get messed and return as INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT have a look at below string

restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=198&deploy=1&columns=internalid,itemid&type=item&filters=matrix;is;F

Comment: @MUHAMMADMUBUSHERASLAM you should try by using a different character over `;` as that is a reserved character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178024/can-a-url-contain-a-semicolon-and-still-be-valid#:~:text=Yes%2C%20semicolons%20are%20valid%20in,marks%2C%20quotes%2C%20etc..