# How to check oauth credentials are valid or not in Netsuite?

Tags: oauth, netsuite

I could get access token and secret, but they are not working some times . I am getting error like invalid login attempt. I don't know how to solve this issue.

I have all the credentials for oauth , these are

1. Consumer key
2. Consumer secret
3. Account id
4. Token id
5. Token Secret
6. Script id
7. Deployment id

I want to know my oauth credentials by group or individual are valid or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to hit SuiteTalk or RESTlet.

If you are using RESTlet, you must ensure that the user has access to RESTlet in the deployment options.

I have a working code using Java (using `Scribe Java` Library) which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33184538/2159867)

MAIN Method:

```
OAuthConfig authConfig = new OAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", null, SignatureType.Header, null, null);
    Token token = new Token("TOKEN_ID", "TOKEN_SECRET");
    OAuth10aServiceImpl auth10aServiceImpl = new OAuth10aServiceImpl(new NetSuiteApi(), authConfig);
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "RESTLET_URL");
    request.setRealm("NS_ACCOUNT_ID");
    auth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(token, request);
    Response response = request.send();
```

Also you will need to write NetSuiteApi Class extending `DefaultApi10a`

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;

public class NetSuiteApi extends DefaultApi10a {

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks prasun for giving assurance about the only way. i will try in php.

Comment: i want to know some details about netsuite . can u join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102873/netsuite?