# How to deal with `;` with `urllib.parse.parse_qsl()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

`;` can not be dealt by `parse_qsl()`. Is there a way to make it aware of `;`? Thanks.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qsl('http://example.com/?q=abc&p=1;2;3')
[('http://example.com/?q', 'abc'), ('p', '1')]
```

Comment: Basically, you (or in this case `urllib.parse.parse_qsl()`) are supposed to treat ";" like "&" in a URL. So `urllib` sees your URL the same way as it would see `http://example.com/?q=abc&p=1&2&3`. If you can, you should encode the semicolons in the URL like this: `http://example.com/?q=abc&p=1%3B2%3B3` or separate the numbers with commas instead of semicolons. If you don't control the URLs you might have to parse the querystring yourself.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1178285/495319

Comment: Could you post the complete solution as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to make sure that the URLs you are dealing with have the semicolons URL encoded. e.g. `http://example.com/?q=abc&p=1%3B2%3B3`

If for some reason you can't do the above, you could do something like this:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, unquote_plus

url = "http://example.com/?q=abc&p=1;2;3"
parts = urlparse(url)
qs = parts.query
pairs = [p.split("=", 1) for p in qs.split("&")]
decoded = [(unquote_plus(k), unquote_plus(v)) for (k, v) in pairs]
```

```
>>> decoded
[('q', 'abc'), ('p', '1;2;3')]
```

The above code assumes a few things about the query string. e.g. that all keys have values. If you want something that makes fewer assumptions, see the [`parse_qsl` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L669:L727).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does treat them correctly (as delimiters).  You just have to tell it to keep blank values:

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qsl('q=abc&p=1;2;3', keep_blank_values=True)
[('q', 'abc'), ('p', '1'), ('2', ''), ('3', '')]
```

Note that you should not be passing the entire url to `parse_qsl`, only the querystring part.

Comment: I think for this case, 1;2;3 are all the value of p.

Comment: No, it's not correct. For that the querystring should look like `q=abc&p=1%3B2%3B3`, if you receive an unencoded querystring then you have some problem elsewhere and need to address it there (otherwise you will eventually get double-decoding bugs).

Comment: Semicolon is in RFC 1738 reserved characters (';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=' and '&') so needs to be urlencoded in the querystring.

Comment: I am not talking about the RFC. I am talking about the specific example. Obviously the website which my example is derived does not following this RFC.

Comment: The querystring is data received from *client*.  When client sends malformed request, you should send them back 400 response.  Do not work around it and try to parse corrupt data.