# Spring boot exact comma next to the path variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

I have an spring boot app with 2.1.0.RELEASE version.

I have  a path variable in my url like `@GetMapping("/{type}/car")` and I call my app with:

```
http://localhost:8080/BMW;AAAAAAAAAAAAA/car
```

But i get only BMW string. Spring skip exact comma and "AAAAAAAAAAAAA".

I apply a filter and I have a same expereince with it. I wanna get path variable like "BMW;AAAAAAAAAAAAA", but I dont get it.

The reason why I want to filter this kind of call out, because it is a security hole.

Comment: I don't think you can use a semicolon like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178024/can-a-url-contain-a-semicolon-and-still-be-valid

Comment: You need to escape your semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a possible solution:

```
@Configuration
public class SolutionConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Override
protected PathMatchConfigurer getPathMatchConfigurer() {
    PathMatchConfigurer pathMatchConfigurer = super.getPathMatchConfigurer();
    UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
    pathMatchConfigurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    return pathMatchConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Source code link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.java

Key method name is "removeSemicolonContent".

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding first, the value will be this `BMW%3BAAAAAAAAAAAAA`, you can use `UriUtils` for encoding and decoding.