# Spring MVC application not intercepting request while access through ";" in the path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application where interceptors are added and it is working fine.

Example:
For `https://example.com/some.action` is been intercepted and `serve.action` is been served

I have recently seen request `https://example.com/.;/some.action` is serving `serve.action` but not passing through interceptor.

Please help me understand what happens when '/.;/' is passed and why interception doesn't work in that case.

Comment: Have a read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1178053/2478398).

Comment: Thank you @BeUndead, didn't understand why the interception is not working in that situation.